# cannot run parse-csv function using async waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, asynchronous

I am trying to request a url, get a csv file from it and then turn that csv into json. I am using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) and [csv-parser](https://github.com/mafintosh/csv-parser)

I have this code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async'),
    request = require('request'),
    csv = require('csv-parser'),
    fileUrl = 'http://forever.codeforamerica.org/fellowship-2015-tech-interview/Violations-2012.csv'

var getData = function(cb){
    request(fileUrl, function(err, response, body){
        (err) ? cb(err) : cb(null, body);
    })
};

var parseCsv = function(csvData, cb){
    var violations = [];
    fs.createReadStream(csvData)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', function(violation){
            violations.push(violation)
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            cb(null, violations)
        })
}

// run the functions
async.waterfall([
    getData,
    parseCsv
], function(err, results){
    if (err) return err;

    console.log('this does not log')
})
```

I get the file fine, but each time it logs out the csv data, not the json, no matter what I console.log

Comment: You're not logging any `results`? Show us where you did put the log statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping was not handled correctly, you can pass the 'request' response directly into a pipe.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('async'),
    request = require('request'),
    csv = require('csv-parser'),
    fileUrl = 'http://forever.codeforamerica.org/fellowship-2015-tech-interview/Violations-2012.csv';

var parseCsv = function(cb){
    var violations = [];
    request.get(fileUrl)
    .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', function(violation){
            violations.push(violation);
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            cb(null, violations);
        });
};

// run the functions
async.waterfall([
    parseCsv
], function(err, results){
    console.log(err, results);
});
```

OUTPUT :

> { violation_id: '225880',
>       inspection_id: '289908',
>       violation_category: 'Unsanitary Conditions',
>       violation_date: '2012-10-17 00:00:00',
>       violation_date_closed: '2012-11-08 00:00:00',
>       violation_type: 'Unsanitary Floors or Walls' },   { violation_id: '225905',
>       inspection_id: '289962',
>       violation_category: 'Vegetation',
>       violation_date: '2012-10-26 00:00:00',
>       violation_date_closed: '2013-01-07 00:00:00',
>       violation_type: 'Overgrown Vegetation' },   { violation_id: '224854',
>       inspection_id: '288325'

PS: Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271583/enametoolong-on-request-for-xml-document)